# how to use nodemon after compile of code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodemon

when I run this script `npm run start` .it copy all `server` content to `compiled-server` and run the server

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf src/compiled-server && babel src/server -s -D -d src/compiled-server && cross-env PORT=3020 NODE_ENV=development node src/compiled-server/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

**logs**

```
 > express-es6@1.0.0 start /Users/b0207296/WebstormProjects/React/express-es6
    > rimraf src/compiled-server && babel src/server -s -D -d src/compiled-server && cross-env PORT=3020 NODE_ENV=development node src/compiled-server/index.js

    >src/server/index.js -> src/compiled-server/index.js
    src/server/routes/objects.js -> src/compiled-server/routes/objects.js
    server is listening on localhost:3020
```

**now I want to use `nodemon` in my project , in other words, if any changes 
`server` directory it will again compile all source code and start the server again ?**

Answer (score 2):

Install nodemon like this

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Add in **"scripts"** in package.json like this.

```
'start': "nodemon server.js"
```

Run **npm run start** it will start the server and follows the change.

To watch specific directory like src you could do like this. And run the dev server by **npm run dev**

```
"dev": "nodemon --watch src src/server.js"
```

In your case try to run the server by nodemon by placing it just before it to achieve your goal.

```
//it might look like this 
"start": "rimraf src/compiled-server && babel src/server -s -D -d src/compiled-server && cross-env PORT=3020 NODE_ENV=development nodemon src/compiled-server/index.js"
```

Comment: Also the node on should be instructed to listen to compiled and node_modules only.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as follows:

- Install `nodemon`

`npm install -g nodemon`

- Run below command to start your server and watch changes in src/server

`nodemon --watch src/server`

The last command will watch any changes in the server folder and recompile and start your server if any changes are made.

[Monitoring multiple directories](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#monitoring-multiple-directories)